# Is it redundant to add implied words after infinitive (eg "to share" vs "to share together")

Tags: adverbs, infinitives

I wanted to write something in a message to my department that essentially says "I am thankful for this home we share"...however I initially thought that I would emphasize the cohesion of the group by adding "I am thankful for this home we share together."

I am concerned this is redundant as togetherness is implied by sharing (one cannot share without another!). Any thoughts here?

Comment: See *Tautology Tuesday: “Working in partnership together”* at http://www.claritywritingexperts.com/tautology-tuesday-working-in-partnership-together

Comment: Nice, I think this well captures the concern I had with a bit of humor.

Comment: together could also be exclusionary in certain cases.

Comment: The exclusiveness lurks in the background (unspoken). 'We share together' (but not with them).

Comment: Yes, there is redundancy in your example. If you check other examples here, you will see that this is given too bad a press by some.

Comment: Should I just delete this or answer my own question? I can't seem to close it or accept a comment as an answer.